Plotting image and point cloud in the same graph in R
I want to plot point cloud, data of x and y, and image in R in one graph.
I know how to do it in Python, but can't find analogue to imshow.
I use rasterimage function and plot, but they result in 2 images. And I need one. I want to plot the second above the first one.
Here is what I tried, where mydata is kx2 dataframe
 plot(1:400, ty="n")
 Picture <- readPNG("image.png")
 rasterImage(Picture(1,1,50,50))
 plot(mydata)

I also tried
Picture <- readPNG("image.png")
p <-  as_ggplot(rasterImage(Picture(1,1,50,50)+plot(mydata))

p
But this also does not work and produce empty image.

The rasterImage() function adds to the current plot by default.
However, it takes in a raster object, so you need to convert what you read in with readPNG() using as.raster().
So first, generate your data, and read in your image:
library(png)

set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
mydata <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))
Picture <- readPNG("cat.png")

Then plot your data, add the raster, and if need be, re-add the points on top (or just plot with type='n' to get the proper window and add afterwards).
plot(mydata, ylim=c(-5,5))


rasterImage(image = as.raster(Picture),
            xleft = 1, xright = 5,
            ybottom = 0, ytop = 5)

# re-add the points on top if you wish
points(mydata)

This yields

For completeness' sake, here's the ggplot equivalent (see also this post).
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mydata, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y)) + ylim(-5,5) + 
  annotation_raster(Picture, 
                    xmin = 1, xmax = 5, 
                    ymin = 0, ymax = 5) + # add image
  geom_point() # add points 

p


If you want the image over the points, simply flip the geom_point() and annotation_raster() calls.
For future questions, a minimal working example makes it easier for people to help.

There is an error in ggplot, it says  mapping must be created with 'aes'. You have supplied null. As for pictures, it still plots two graphs — one with image, another one with points. Maybe it should be mentioned that mydata is c(data), where data<-function$column

This is why I mention a minimal working example is required to help you. The code in my answer runs with the data I provide. I cannot guess the type and structure of your data! Please read this post on making a minimal working example and edit your question accordingly.

procOPAr<-c(procOPA(A,B)$Bhat) Picture<-readPNG("cat.png")
plot(procOPAr, ylim=c(0,400)   rasterImage(image=as.raster(Picture), xleft=0,xright=400, ybottom=0, ytop=400)
p <- ggplot(mydata, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y)) + ylim(0,400) +
annotation_raster(Picture,
xmin = 0, xmax = 400,
ymin = 0, ymax = 400)

I read tutorials on aes.   p<-ggplot(procOPA(A,B), mapping= aes(Bhat)+ the same code as before

I read syntax of aes and adjusted code.   p<-ggplot(procOPA(A,B, scale=false reflect=false), mapping= aes(Bhat)+ ylim(0,400)+annotation_raster(Picture, xmin=0, xmax=400, ymin=0, ymax=400))               still doesn't work

Please edit your question post with your data. What you've written here is impossible to understand.
